Pod outdated command results in "Error in the HTTP2 framing layer"
I'm trying to run "pod outdated" to check what versions of pods I have installed, however I always get the error:

CDN: trunk URL couldn't be downloaded:
https://cdn.cocoapods.org/Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/11.5.0/Firebase.podspec.json
Response: Error in the HTTP2 framing layer

While googling for a solution to this, I couldn't find anything relating to pods in general however there are many hits for "Error in the HTTP2 framing layer", so presumably that error is something more generic? And not anything specifically releated to pods? But if that is the case, then I still wasn't able to find any solution regardless.
If it is an issue with pods, then whats the fix?

You may need to specific the source url. Please refer to this
https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/12679
